# Rewrite/Reformat Multiple Nested Sub Queries in a Debug Friendly manner

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery

Is there a better way to rewrite multiple nested sub-queries so that it is easier to understand and debug, without taking a performance hit?

(Note: In my case I got a bunch of rather complex sub-queries, many with multiple joins, where clause and some got case statements etc. Writing everything as one big block of code is a debugging nightmare)

For Example: I want to rewrite this:

```
SELECT DoSomething(x) AS x
FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x) AS x
      FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x) AS x
            FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x) AS x
                  FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x) AS x
                        FROM (SELECT x
                              FROM tbl_1) AS Q1) AS Q2) AS Q3) AS Q4) AS Q5
```

Into something like this:

```
--Q1
SELECT *
INTO #Q1
FROM (SELECT x
      FROM tbl_1) AS Q1

--Q2
SELECT *
INTO #Q2
FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x)
      FROM Q1) AS Q2

--Q3
SELECT *
INTO #Q3
FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x)
      FROM Q2) AS Q3

--Q4
SELECT *
INTO #Q4
FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x)
      FROM Q3) AS Q3

--Q5
SELECT *
INTO #Q5
FROM (SELECT DoSomething(x)
      FROM Q4) AS Q4

--Do Something with Q5 then cleanup

DROP TABLE #Q1
DROP TABLE #Q2
DROP TABLE #Q3
DROP TABLE #Q4
DROP TABLE #Q5
```

The example above although much more code will (hopefully) allow the debugger to view/select single sub-queries more easily and help him/her narrow in on potential problems

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: You can use CTE instead of temporary tables. Something like `With MyCTE01 as (select ... from tbl_1), MyCTE02 as (Select... from MyCTE01), MyCTE03 as (Select... from MyCTE02), ... SELECT .... From MyCTE<use the last cte number> `

Comment: ops... sticky bit  already publish it as answer

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You could write your example like:

```
WITH
Q1
AS
(
SELECT x
       FROM tbl_1
),
Q2
AS
SELECT DoSomething(x)
       FROM Q1
),
Q3
AS
(
SELECT DoSomething(x)
       FROM Q2
),
Q4
AS
(
SELECT DoSomething(x)
       FROM Q3
),
Q5
AS
(
SELECT DoSomething(x)
       FROM Q4
)
SELECT *
       FROM Q5;
```